# Data is getting changed while inserting php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a word for example "A'Bc" it will be inserted into MySQL and displayed as "Aâ€™Bc" upon retrieving how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
$dbs = "INSERT INTO all_asins_task_data (Locale, Task, vendor_name, vendor_code, ASIN, Action, Content, updated_on, user_id, Parent_ASIN, tt_id, value, service, comment, Allocation_type, Week_Number, month, Year) 
VALUES ('".$d1."', '".$d2."', '".$d3."', '".$d4."', '".$d5."', '".$d6."', '".$d7."', '".$r."','".$_SESSION['login_user']."', '".$d8."', '".$d9."', '".$d10."','".$d11."', '".$d12."','".$d13."','".$d14."','".$monthName."','".$year."')";
$run = mysql_query($dbs);
```

Comment: What's your retrieving mechanism? your own PHP script?

Comment: Hi Marc Delisle,

Full file is in the below link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LQzYCPteKANzx2G2rZ4rRtRa8zJCJ0Ft

Comment: Also, I am facing another issue, for example if I upload 100 rows of data, sometimes it will upload only 90 and sometimes it will upload 80 rows of data to the database.

What might be the reason?

Comment: I found answer for the above issue I was facing the reason is if the data consists of words for example AB'C it is not getting uploaded. If the same words are written as ABC it will get upload. That is the reason sometimes 90 rows and sometimes 80 rows was getting uploaded. How to read the word AB'C and upload the same to the database?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found out answer for my question.

First of all the reason why data was not inserting, my php code was only reading values without special character. So, then I have added the line "mysql_real_escape_string" where ever necessary.

Now data is inserting correctly.

Thanks for the help @Marc Delisle.